# Subroutine that stops script to prompt user to hit Enter only works correctly on the first call

Tags: vbscript

I am trying my hand at vbscript and just running very basic code and I am guessing there is a simple solution that I cannot find. I am running this is CMD with cscript.

I have a subroutine named Pause that is suppose to stop the script and ask the user to hit Enter to continue.

```
sub Pause(strPause)
    WScript.Echo (strPause)
    Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfLine
        Input = WScript.StdIn.Read(1)
    Loop
End sub
```

I am calling this subroutine in a simple loop that is printing out 1 to 10. It pauses correctly after the first call but after that it just prints out the rest with no pause. It still echos the Pause String so it seems to be hitting the Sub.

```
For i = 1 To 10
    ' Print i to the Output window.
    Wscript.echo"loop index is " & i
    ' Wait for user to resume.
    Pause("Press Enter to continue")    
Next
```

Not sure if the Do While loop inside the sub is causing issues or if Input value needs to be cleared somehow? It seems to work a little better when the Do While loop is removed from the Sub, Pausing after every two numbers instead of just printing out everything. Yet I can still not get it to pause after each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the commented out `Do Loop` and the change to the `Input =` line. Looks like you don't need the loop, rather just read a line at a time.

```
Sub Pause(strPause)
    WScript.Echo (strPause)
    'Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfLine
        Input = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
    'Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Figured the loop was not necessary but the ReadLine was definitely throwing me. Works perfect, Thank you!